# Using BeautifulSoup to Parse HTML Table Returns b' ' in Each Cell

Tags: python, html, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse an HTML table and write it to a CSV. The code that I have works, but it returns `b'<value>'` for each cell in the table that has a value, and `b''` for each cell in the table that is null. Does anyone know why this would be?

Unfortunately, the URL in question is not reachable over the public internet, but here is my code for review without it:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib
    import csv
    import time
    url = <not accessible over public internet>
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("table")
    headers = [th.text.encode("utf-8") for th in table.select("tr th")]
    with open("test_" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + ".csv", "w") as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f)
        wr.writerow(headers)
        wr.writerows([[td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.select("tr + tr")])
```

Lastly, here's a screenshot example of the output I'm talking about. (Forgive the ugliness resulting from editing out sensitive stuff.)

[Example_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOKVm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit to this to only allow values with text in them; (the if td.text section below). (Assuming you dont want the null values)

```
wr.writerows([[td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in row.find_all("td") if td.text] for row in table.select("tr + tr")])
```

**UPDATE:** 
Modify open the csv command to

```
with open("test_" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + ".csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Then remove the encoding from the csv write

```
wr.writerows([[td.text for td...............
```

Comment: Thanks, that did remove all the null values, but the non-null values are still wrapped in `b'<value>'` as opposed to just `<value>`. See my "Example_Output" screenshot.

Comment: That's the bytes literal, which indicates the data is not a string (caused because you encoded data to UTF-8. Python ignores that in comparisons etc, so it should not be a worry. If you want to remove it though, try solution added above.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `b''` is not part of the string. It is part of the representation of a byte-literal, in exactly the same way that in the string `"foo"` or `'foo'`, only `foo` is the string, and the quotes are just part of the visual representation. You convert between unicode strings and byte strings using `encode` and `decode` methods.